# Smarty concat and use as a variable

Tags: php, smarty, concatenation

In PHP file I am running a loop and within it I am assigning a variable for smarty.

PHP CODE:

```
foreach($pindata as $Idx => $Val)
{
    $pinId = $Val['id'];
    $sql = mysql_query("select count(userID) as users from pinrest_supporters where pin_id = $pinId;");
    $contributorsSql = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $contributors = $contributorsSql['users'];
    $smarty->assign("contributors$pinId", $contributors);

}
```

So the values assigned in smarty are `contributors1038`, `contributors1039` and so onnn.

Now my problem is that I want to use these assigned variables in smarty dynamically.

In smarty template file if I write `{$contributors1038}` then I get a correct output as 9. But I want to use it dynamically. 1038 is the ID, and I have that in my template. If I try to concat the two different variables and expecting the result, I am failed :P

I tried this:

`{assign var='contri' value="contributors"|cat:$results[res].id}`

But the above variable `{$contri}` gives me result as *contributors1038*

I want to make a new variable by joining two different variable, but this makes it as string. So can anyone help me?

Comment: try to use `value=$contributors` in `assign`, maybe this will work.

Comment: when I try something like this `{assign var='contri' value=$contributors|cat:$results[res].id}` Then I am just getting the ID i.e. 1048

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I am exhausted trying different solutions, so finally I am doing this to achieve my target.

Instead of below code
PHP

```
$contributors = $contributorsSql['users'];
$smarty->assign("contributors$pinId", $contributors);
```

I made the smarty variable an array

PHP

```
$contributors[$pinId] = $contributorsSql['users'];
$smarty->assign("contributors", $contributors);
```

And in smarty I am calling it as

SMARTY:

```
{$contributed[$results[res].id]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only aim is of outputting the data, you can try it this way

```
{$contributors}{$results[res].id}
```

Comment: @ntechi what o/p are you getting??

Comment: only the ID, coz there is no variable as `$contributors` all variables are `$contributors1038`, `$contributors1039` etc